# How to know audio route in HTML5 (Chrome Browser - iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, html, google-chrome, web-audio-api

We developed an iOS app that could generate sound by itself (pure tones, white noises, filtered noises). We are evaluating the migration to HTML5 in order to be hardware independent.
In iOS audio route can be known and also an event is triggered when the route is changed. For example, when headphones are inserted.

Is this possible in HTML 5?

We are thinking of using Google Chrome as browser and the OS would be iOS and Android. Sound would be generated with WebAudio API...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The model for Web Audio (and audio in HTML5 in general) does not today have input/output control at that granularity.  The default output is the only one exposed, and in the case you mention, there's no event that tells you that headphones have been inserted; it's all just the default audio interface.